# Using vectors instead of loops in R

Tags: r

I'm going through R tutorial http://data.princeton.edu/R/gettingStarted.html
At the end of the page they ask to " Simulate 20 observations from the regression model Y = a+b x + e using the x vector generated above. Set a = 1 and b = 2. Use standard normal errors generated as rnorm(20), where 20 is the number of observations."
The only way to do it I can think of is:

```
error <- rnorm(20)
x <- 1:10
Y <- matrix(rep(1,200),20,10)
for (i in seq(1,20,1)) {
  Y[i,1:10] <- 1+2*x+error[i]
  }
```

This seems to work, but I'm curios if more elegant solution, without for loop, is available?

Comment: `x <- [1:10]` isn't valid. Did you just want `x <- 1:10`

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing this out, I mistyped, will fix it

Answer (score 2):

I think the direction to use `rnorm(20)` confuses, better:

```
a=1
b=2
x=1:10
replicate(20, a+(b*x)+rnorm(1))
```

then everything just recycles as it should

Comment: It might be the case, thank you.  But still would be interesting to see a solution with rnorm(20) for my learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to your code. I use the highly optimize `apply` function.

```
> set.seed(1)
> error <- rnorm(20)
> x <- 1:10
> t(apply(matrix(error), 1, function(e) 1 + (2*x) + e) )
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a very nice solution.  Is set.seed(1) here optional? 
And apply translates to:  
for each element e from matrix error[20][1] do: 1+2*x+e. ?  I'm just trying to wrap my head around this apply function.

Comment: `set.seed` is just to obtain the same values from the random generator for you to reproduce the example and compare mine result to yours. `apply` is getting each element rowise from `matrix(error)` and pass it to the anonymous function `1 + (2*x) + e` ;) Take a llok at `?apply`