# use vector instead of loop in R

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

Consider the following simplified loop

```
value<-rep(NA,100000)

system.time(for (i in 1:100000) {
  x <- rnorm(600,0,1) 
  value[i]<- mean(x) 
})

   user  system elapsed
  6.839   0.184   7.025
```

How can we optimize this loop using vectors? Is it possible to make it run faster?

I know there are similar posts, like this [Using vectors instead of loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246919/using-vectors-instead-of-loops) but my question is a bit different in terms of where the random draw is taken.

Comment: I think my method has separate draws, since it draws in each iteration.. No? The method you are suggesting with vectors doesn't make things faster. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Even a (theoretical) vectorized solution is still going to call rnorm 1e5 times.

Comment: Thanks @blindJesse. So no hope to improve...

Comment: @prog_newbie, can't test right now, but how does `colMeans(matrix(rnorm(600*n, 0, 1), ncol = n)` compare (where `n` can be set to the number of replications, in this case 100000)?

Comment: @AnandaMahto - seems marginally quicker than `for` or `replicate`, which would be: `replicate(n, mean(rnorm(600,0,1)))`

Comment: @AnandaMahto, a closing bracket is missing.

Comment: Yeap, I did the `replicate` on my own, gave me something like `6.5 s` and the `colMeans` gives something around `6 s`. But the mostly useful solution would be to use vector in a way to reduce much more I think, if possible of course :)

Comment: @prog_newbie The bottleneck is the random number generator. You can try to find a faster one than the one `rnorm` uses, but its quality would be expected to be inferior. I don't think you can get much faster than Ananda's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop doesn't use much time in that. Calling rnorm to make a single vector taking means of sections later use the zoo package `rollmean` was much slower.

```
value<-rep(NA,100000)
system.time(for (i in 1:100000) {
  x <- rnorm(600,0,1) 
  value[i]<- mean(x) 
})
user  system elapsed 
8.873   0.020   8.905 

system.time(y <- rnorm(600*100000,0,1))
 user  system elapsed 
6.748   0.112   6.874

x<-rep(NA,100000)
system.time(for (i in 1:100000) {
  x <- rnorm(600,0,1) 
})
 user  system elapsed 
7.116   0.020   7.150 

value<-rep(NA,100000)
system.time(for (i in 1:100000) {
  value[i]<- mean(x) 
})
 user  system elapsed 
0.924   0.000   0.924
```

Ananda's idea from comments gives a pretty similar time to the loop.

```
system.time(x <- colMeans(matrix(rnorm(600*100000, 0, 1), ncol = 100000)))
 user  system elapsed 
7.873   0.232   8.119
```